# mongodb $all and $in very slow even on indexed fields

Tags: mongodb

I have a collection of about 80 million documents, each of them storing an array of tags in the `tags` field, e.g:

```
{text: "blah blah blah...", tags: ["car", "auto", "automobile"]}
```

The field `tags` is indexed, so naturally the queries like this are almost instant:

```
 db.documents.find({tags:"car"})
```

However the following queries are all very slow, taking several minutes to complete:

```
 db.documents.find({tags:{$all:["car","phone"]}})
 db.documents.find({tags:{$in:["car","auto"]}})
```

The problem persists even if the array only has a single item:

```
 db.documents.find({tags:{$all:["car"]}})  //very slow too
```

I thought $all and $in should be able to work very fast because `tags` is indexed but apparently it is not the case. Why?

Comment: meybe tags => 'car' without $all,  or see: http://blog.mongodb.org/post/16015854270/operations-in-the-new-aggregation-framework.Find on page  CTRL + F  -> $unwind

Comment: `tags:'car'` works fine, but I need to search for documents containing multiple tags. Also, what is strange is that `{tags:{$all:["car"]}}` is orders of magnitude slower than `tags:'car'` even though it is equivalent and produces virtually the same `.explain()` output

Comment: Hmm 80 million documents -> when you again run the same query did you see any improvment in time. You collection size is your Ram is ?

Comment: Now that you mentioned it, I checked collection stats() and it turns out that total index size (8gb) does not fit into RAM on my development laptop (3gb). This is probably what causes problems, though single tag searches still work very fast.

Comment: Yep swamping is the issue. So better try: tags => ('car','auto') OR tags => ('car'), tags => 'auto'

Comment: @Userpassword Turned out to be a known bug/misfeature after all, see https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-1000

Answer (score 9):

It turns out this is a known bug in MongoDB which hasn't yet been fixed as of 2.2

MongoDB does *not* perform index intersection when searching for multiple entries using `$all`. Only the first item in the array is looked up using indexes, and a scan of all matched documents is performed to filter the results.

For example, in the query `db.documents.find({tags:{$all:["car","phone"]}})` all documents containing the tag "car" need to be retrieved and scanned. Since the collection in question contains over a hundred thousand documents tagged with "car", the slowdown is not surprising.

Worse, MongoDB doesn't even perform the simple optimization of selecting the least represented item in the $all array for the index lookup. If there are 100000 documents tagged "car" and 10 documents tagged "phone", MongoDB will still need to scan 100000 documents to return results for `{$all:["car", "phone"]}`

See also: https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-1000

Answer (score -1):

I just want to add, $in is fast. In fact, for just 1 criteria or keyword, $in is equivalent with $all, yet $in is fast, and $all is slow.

So use $in.